# Smarty, вывод определённого элемента массива

Tags: php, smarty

Добрый день! Подскажите, как лучше сделать следующее: есть фрагмент в шаблоне, вот он:

```
 {foreach from=$shortcutTopMenu.$name item=item}
          <a href="{$item.URL}"><span>{$item.LABEL}</span></a>
 {/foreach}
```

Мне нужно вывести только перый результат итерации foreach, т.е сейчас создаётся список, мне в этом списке нужен только первый элемент, как-нибудь можно красиво ограничить область foreach?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первый вариант - использовать [{break}](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.foreach.tpl#foreach.construct.break)

```
{foreach from=$shortcutTopMenu.$name item=item}
    <a href="{$item.URL}"><span>{$item.LABEL}</span></a>
    {break}
{/foreach}
```

Еще один вариант, не делать foreach, а сразу взять первый элемент массива

```
{assign var="item" value=$shortcutTopMenu[$name][0]}
<a href="{$item.URL}"><span>{$item.LABEL}</span></a>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! В принципе я так и сделал (второй вариант), с первым я тоже пробовал, но это не совсем правильно городить цикл, там где он не будет использоваться и первый вариант не работал. Ещё раз спасибо.